# Why element does not go smaller than padding?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to shrink elements smaller than their paddings.
But I cannot.
I want `box` to be 5px. But it is 80px because I have `padding: 40px`

How can I make `box` 5px without removing paddings?
I tried to make it `flex`. But it didn't help.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*   display: flex; */
}

.box {
  /*   flex: 1; */
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the padding if you don't want it?

Comment: @Paulie_D I want element to shrink when window size is resized. And I want to shrink below padding size.

Comment: padding will be include as long as it can be but won't be scaled down. You can use value using the viewport (vh,vw,vmin,vmax) as a plain value or inside a calc() or clamp() calculated value

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyrillus! But I don't want to scale padding. I just want to shrink element smaller than paddings when window is resized.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. I'd suggest a media query to reduce the padding when the viewport changes. This sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: Good to know that this is not possible. Thank you @Paulie_D!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong and you want to make your .box div to smaller size use below css.

```
.box {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 10px;
  transform: scale(0.5); //this will make you box smaller without removing the padding
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Let me try this @Nikkkshit

Comment: yeah I see `box` becomes smaller. But I see space between boxes now.
Is this possible to avoid space between boxes?

Comment: I think you should use media queries. Rather than trying to make box small size without removing padding.